# c# mstest test the method that query database throws a FileNotFoundException when it was reading config

Tags: c#, configuration, mstest

i want to create a test project and import a solution(solution A) so that i don't need to add a test project in the solution. I want to separate the test project and others because i don't want SVN know I have created it.

When I test a method that query data from database by Entity Framwork. It throws an Exception:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=*************'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

But i check the Dependencies->SDK->Microsoft.NETCore App(2.1) , i found System.Configuration.dll.

What's happening to me? I search in stack overflow, and try to copy the config to test project from the solution A. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two reason:

1. I use a .net core project(the test project) to call a method in standard ,net framework project.
2. All test project need to install ConfigurationManager in Nuget.

====================== UPDATE MY ANSWER ABOVE =================

I gave up to use mstest to do it.

I found another way to do but it seems a bit stupid.I directly wrote test method in controller.

First, declare a TestBean.

```
public TestBean(string name, string suppose, string fact, object msg = null)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.suppose = suppose;
    this.fact = fact;
    pass = suppose == fact;
    if (SHOW_MSG)
        this.msg = msg;
    else
        this.msg = null;
}
```

Use the bean like this in controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public string TestAll(){
    JObject obj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(TestMethod());
    TestBean beans = new TestBean[]{
        new TestBean('TestMethod',true+"",obj+"",obj)
    };
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(beans);
}
```

When I visit the url localhost:.../TestAll, I will get json

```
[
    {
        "pass":true,
        "name":"TestMethod",
        "suppose":"True",
        "fact":"True",
        "msg":"True"
    }
]
```

Honestly, it's not easy to use, especially when the test case change frequently.